# How to run an AHK script on Windows startup when the script is associated with a text editor

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey, file-association

I have an AutoHotkey script and it should be started each time on Windows startup. For this purpose, it is located in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

The problem is that my AHK scripts are associated with Sublime Text, not the AHK interpreter. (Typically, when I need to run a script, I open it in Sublime Text and then press <kbd>F1</kbd>. I have a special package for it.)

Hence, on Windows startup, this script is opened in Sublime Text instead of being started. Is there a way to *start* it?

Bad workarounds I'm aware of:

- To associate `.ahk` files with AHK interpreter.
- To convert `.ahk` file to `.exe`.
- To start `.bat` or `.ps1` file to start `.ahk` file. (That is, it is assumed that `.ahk` files are associated with Sublime Text, but `.bat` and `.ps1` files are associated with the corresponding interpreters. I call this workaround "bad" because these file types are as well already associated with Sublime Text.)

Comment: Why don't you change the file association and try? Associate your .ahk files with AHK Interpreter and test it. If your script is launched on startup, you're good, if not, well, you can revert to Sublime Text if you want. AHK-to-exe would be a better option, IMO, but that's just me: Windows know what to do with .exe files, after all. Did you place a *shortcut* of your script in the Startup folder? Because that's the way to do it in shell:startup or shell:common startup (system-wide). Not copy the file itself, but its shortcut. EDIT: I suppose you've thought of, and discarded, Task scheduler?

Comment: @Diader Yes, it is a good idea to use a shortcut, but I slightly improved it. Shortcut contents: `Target` = `"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" D:\path\to\the\script\script.ahk`, `Start In` = `D:\path\to\the\script` (default). It seems it works for me.

Comment: That's good enough for me, then! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

In the *Startup* directory, create a shortcut with the following parameters:

*Target*:

```
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" D:\path\to\the\script\script.ahk
```

*Start In*:

```
D:\path\to\the\script
```

**Option 2:**

You could also try to use Task Scheduler, but I haven't tried it myself.