# How to send some commands of AHK to a specific program automatically without press any key, just by running the specific program in each time?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Hy

- I'm new to Autohotkey and I use V1.1+
- I would like to send some commands of AHK to a specific program automatically without press any key just by running the specific program in each time I run it, example:
- In each time I run the specific ("Program.exe") by clicking on its shortcut on the desktop I want to send it some commands automatically after running it without press any key.
- I've tried this, but didn't work:

  ```
  #If WinActive("ahk_exe programe.exe")
  WinWait, ahk_exe programe.exe
  CoordMode, Mouse, Window
  ControlClick, x86 y143,,,Right,1
  Sleep, 2000
  ControlClick,x282 y130 ,,,Click, 2
  send, abcd
  return
  #If
  ```
- Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do that with a *batch file* that first runs the AutoHotKey command and then starts the application, or *vice versa*. Make a shortcut to the .bat file on the desktop.

For example, use the following two-line script in a .bat file, [adapted from another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1537094/how-to-run-an-ahk-script-on-windows-startup-when-the-script-is-associated-with-a):

```
start "C:\Program File\app folder\app.exe"
"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" D:\path\to\the\script\script.ahk
```

You might need to reverse the order of the lines, or modify use of [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to begin the application and immediately jump to AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method in AHK V1 is to use the
[Process command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Process.htm)
like this:

```
loop {
    Process, Wait, programe.exe
    Sleep, 1000
    ... send clicks ...
    Process, WaitClose, programe.exe
}
```

This will give the program one second to initialize itself
before sending it the clicks.